# Reason for congestion in CSMA based networks

Tags: ieee-802.11, packet-loss, congestion

A typical channel with SNR 10dB and BW 10 MHz will have a channel capacity of something around 150 Mbps. In CSMA, at  any given time, only 1 user is allowed to transmit and in 802.11p, the default rate is 6 Mbps. So a channel whose capacity is 150 Mbps is only utilized of its 6 Mbps.
In such scenario, why does a situation of channel congestion arise > I understand hidden nodes will be an issue, but is the channel congestion a result of hidden nodes entirely or am I missing something?

Comment: Generally, congestion happens when more than one node try to access a single channel. Of course, congestion is more likely when the channel has low capacity (or when there are many potential nodes). What's the special scenario?

Comment: A typical chanel as described above can carry around 150 Mbps, and of 1 user is transmitting, he will transmit data at rate 6Mbps. So how is congestion happening ? In TCP, when a number of users send data and the total data sent by all reaches the channel capacity, congestion occurs. But in CSMA, only 1 user is allowed to access the channel at any given time. So why does congestion occur in CSMA ?

Comment: The channel's capacity depends on the modulation & mode used at any given time. When a 6 Mbit/s mode is used, that's the channel capacity since you can't have concurrent transfer. TCP is entirely irrelevant to the physical layer channel, it's two layers further up.

Comment: From my understanding, capacity defined by Shannon is the theoretical max data that can be transferred any given time. Now using a specific MCS, I transfer only 6 mbps of the total capacity, which is arguably much higher. So why would congestion occur in such a scenario even if another user transfers data at 6 mbps, as total  utilization is 6+6 = 12 mbps and shannon's capacity is much higher.

Comment: The channel capacity defined by Shannon is the *theoretical limit* of that channel. Any protocol you run on that channel imposes its own limits, just like 802.11 in your case. Since there can be only one transmitter active at any time, the transmitter occupies the channel for its transmission period, *regardless of transmission speed*. The difference between the current channel speed and the Shannon capacity cannot be used and is wasted.

Comment: I see, and now regarding the congestion: by design CSMA allows only 1 user to occupy the channel at any time. _So if there is congestion, it must be due to some hidden node effect where the transmitter couldn't sense that the channel was being used by someone out of his sensing range_. Is that right ?

Comment: Not quite. A radio channel supports only one transmitter at a time, it is inherently half-duplex. CSMA/CA is a way to arbitrate the channel. The hidden station problem is better solved with the optional RTS/CTS scheme.